# Get the value from the CheckBox Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

How can I get the value from the CheckBox Control before is selected?? It doesn´t have a .Value method.

```
else if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox)) // c is control
{
      string textValue= ((CheckBox)(c)).Text; // here I take the text
     string value= ((CheckBox)(c)).????; //how should I take the value?
```

Comment: Whats difference b/w text and value of a checkbox? I think its same.

Comment: the text is the one the use sees at the browser... the value would be the one behind the code

Comment: You talking about true-false?

Comment: nop, for example if the code in .asp is :
`<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" Value="MYVALUE" Text="kkk" />`
I´d like to get "MYVALUE"

Comment: Checkbok will only returns true or false boolean as a value. It cannot return string or any other value.

Comment: You can get check box value as  bool value =  CheckBox1.Checked

Answer (score 5):

```
myCheckbox.Checked
```

returns true or false based on the state of the checkbox.

Comment: Your checkbox control

Answer (score 2):

You must get `Value` attribute.

```
string Value = checkbox1.Attributes["Value"];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :
((CheckBox)(c)).Checked.ToString()

Comment: it returns False value

Comment: Well this is what "value" means in checkbox.

Comment: Try AutoPostBack="true" on your check box in the aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

```
<input id="chkBox1" name="chkbo" type="checkbox" value="myvalue" runat="server" />
```

and then you can get the value field from behind :

```
chkBox1.value;
```